# Language redirection

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm new to programming. Decided to create and launch my first website. It consists only of 2 html pages. Page one is in Russian (default) and page 2 is in English.

I want JS to redirect to the English page all the users who have their browsers languages not in Russian.

So I tried to use this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
        if (userLang == "ru") {
            break;
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = "/en/index.html"
        }
    });
</script>
```

But nothing happened.

Comment: Remove your `break;` line, that's giving you errors that are not letting your script fully run, also you don't need jQuery for it to work, you can run it as a simple JS script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `break` statement is invalid there. Also, what you're trying to achieve doesn't need an else statement - you can redirect user to the english version `if` the language **is not** russian.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function(){
            var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
            if (userLang !== "ru") {
                window.location.href = "/en/index.html";
            }
        });
    </script>
```

This is your code after a little tweak. As someone already mentioned - you could achieve that easily without jQuery.

Comment: My problem didn't go away. The code switches to the english page even if the language of the browser is Russian. And I can't manuaylly redirect it to the russian page.